# Create a 3 line menu icon which scales with font

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a 3 line menu that relies less on px dimensions and more on em. It basically needs to scale with the font.

Here is what I have so far

http://jsfiddle.net/K3KT3/

```
body {
    padding: 5%;
}
.btn {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:2%;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 36px;
    width:36px;
}
#lines:before {
    border-bottom: 17px double black;
    border-top: 6px solid black;
    content:"";
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    right:3px;
    top: 4px;
    width:30px;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Convert your pixel values to em. Or use an icon font.

Comment: @Jrod That's a request for us to do work. Not a question.